# Consultar el valor máximo de una tabla en sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo estas 3 consultas

```
SELECT max(area_aut) from autorizaciones where id = 'Variable a buscar' and Area = 'A' 
SELECT max(area_aut) from autorizaciones where id = 'Variable a buscar' and Area = 'B' 
SELECT max(area_aut) from autorizaciones where id = 'Variable a buscar' and Area = 'C'
```

Como podria dejarla en una sola convertirla en una sola consulta ya que necesito actualizar una tabla, pero no se como hacerlo en una sola consulta

Comment: Estás Buscando `MAX(area)` pero también estás indicando que `area = 'A'`. ¿Qué esperas que sea el resultado?

Comment: era area_aut, me habia faltado pero con la respuesta de Lamak es completamente funcional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ésta es una forma:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN area = 'A' THEN area END) AreaA,
    MAX(CASE WHEN area = 'B' THEN area END) AreaB,
    MAX(CASE WHEN area = 'C' THEN area END) AreaC
FROM autorizaciones 
WHERE id = 'Variable a buscar' 
AND Area IN ('A','B','C') 
;
```

Comment: Me sirvió tu ayuda, solo que me había faltado agregarle bien el nombre de la tabla, pero ya solo la modifique asi:

Comment: SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN area_aut = 'A' THEN area END) AreaA,
    MAX(CASE WHEN area_aut = 'B' THEN area END) AreaB,
    MAX(CASE WHEN area_aut = 'C' THEN area END) AreaC
FROM autorizaciones 
WHERE id = 'Variable a buscar' 
AND Area IN ('A','B','C') 
;

Comment: Tendrías algún ejemplo donde esto mismo lo pueda pasar a entity framework